# Using JSON object using Angular and rest service

Tags: json, angularjs, rest

I have this service method

```
public object Get(EmployeeAccountsRequest request)
{
    var list=userList.ToList();
    var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(list);
    return json;
}
```

Definition of EmployeeAccountRequest request class

```
[Route("/employeeaccount", "GET")]
public class AllUserAccountsRequest : IReturn<object>
{
    public int projectNumber{ get; set; }
    public int class{ get; set; }
}
```

which returns following JSON object.

```
[{"name": "Moroni", "allowance": 550,  "paid": true},
{"name": "Tiancum", "allowance": 53,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Jacob", "allowance": 27,  "paid": false}]
```

Resource to get this data from service is as following:

```
  angular.module('accService', ['ngResource']).factory('EmployeeAccount', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/employeeaccount/:id', {}, {
      get: {
        method: 'GET',
      },      
      query: {
        method: 'GET',
      },
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      },
    });
  });
```

And trying to receive this value in controller

```
  var app = angular.module('EmployeeApp');
  app.controller('EmployeeAccountsController', function($scope, $http, EmployeeAccount) {


  console.log(EmployeeAccount.query())
}
```

But i am not receiving the JSON object here.
The above setup works fine if i return a list of array from my method.

So the question becomes why would a list of array is received properly and not a simple JSON object. Please let me know, if more information is needed.

Comment: are you injecting employeeAccount?

Comment: Can you inspect the request using the Network tab of the Dev Tools console? See what the raw response looks like. You're sure that your server is returning valid JSON?